# How do you copy files using ditto with backslashes in filenames

Tags: macos, bash, regex, find, sed

Im writing a script to copy files with characters unsupported by Office365 to a cache folder on OSX before removing the characters (that part omitted).  This works except in the case of files such as:

```
p\\ophaddy.jpg
```

where ditto interprets the backslash as a space and fails understandably. Trying to figure out the most efficient way of doing this.

```
find $HOME  -not \( -path "$HOME/Library" -prune \) -not \( -path "$HOME/Cache" -prune \) -not \( -path "$HOME/.Trash" -prune \)  -name "*[<>:/|?#%\\\]*" -exec bash -c 'x="{}" && echo $x && ditto "$x" $HOME/Cache/ ; y=$(sed "s/[<>:|?#%\\\]\+/-/g" <<< "$x")   ' \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Ubuntu, so I don't have `ditto`, but the following should work:

```
find $HOME  -not \( -path "$HOME/Library" -prune \) \
            -not \( -path "$HOME/Cache" -prune \) \
            -not \( -path "$HOME/.Trash" -prune \) \
            -name "*[<>:/|?#%\\\]*" | while read -r; \
  do cp --parent --preserve-all "${REPLY}" "$HOME/Cache/${REPLY/[<>:|?#%\\]/-}"; \
  done
```

Notes:-

- I have spread the command over several lines for legibility.
- This doesn't do quite what you were trying to achieve: the above replaces each individual invalid character by `-`, while you try to replace each sequence of invalid characters by a single `-`, though both yield Office-compatible files.
- In general, I prefer piping to `read`, rather than `-exec bash /c ...`, which needs great care over the use of quoting and escaping.

Comment: Thanks, I had to use Rsync -R rather than CP as --parent is not available on OS X

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that: I have since found the OSX manual on-line, and `cp` is quite restricted in comparison with Linux versions, where `-a` copies directory structures and `--parent` is a spin-off from this handling. Because `cp` is so powerful, I've never needed `rsync` on Linux. I shan't try and guess your complete `rsync` command: was `-R` the only option? If you tell me what you used, I'll update my answer so that it is correct for OSX.